# js in rails:About the onclick

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm doing a rails project. Here comes my problem: I have a button_to tag in my .haml file:

`= button_to "Add", add_problem_path(paper, :problem_id => problem.id), :class => 'essay_problem', :id => problem.id, :remote => true, :onclick => 'new function() { if($(".essay#3").val() == "xxxx"){ alert("Please add the essay first!"); return false; } }'`

what I want to do is to make a validation by `onclick()` before it posts to add_problem_path, if the validation is passed then it posts to add_problem_path, or it just alerts and does nothing. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

you are just defining a new function in onclick event

create the function under :javascript in haml file. call it in your onclick function

```
= button_to "Add", add_problem_path(paper, :problem_id => problem.id), :class => 'essay_problem', :id => problem.id, :remote => true, :onclick => 'return validate();'

:javascript
  function validate()
  {
  if($(".essay#3").val() == "xxxx"){ 
  alert("Please add the essay first!"); 
  return false; 
  }
  else
  {
  return true;
  }
  }
```

Comment: I got it. When the `onclick` return false the button_to will not post to the add_problem_path. In the former time, I just return false in the onclick event which means return in the the onclick event. Thanks so much for your help!